# Pass fetched api data by oncheck in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, components

I face some problem what I need to do is " I created react web app in which I call data by fetching api data in list of table. This list contains a check box when click on checkbox how to show data of selected or checked list in another component

Answer (score 0):

You mean when you check this checkbox you get more information about that row?

You can use a state of with the id's of each checked row, then in the other component create a useEffect which listens to this array and do your logics inside of that.